# Zipping a Directory in Python, Losing Metadata

Tags: python, directory, zip, metadata

I have a program that zips up a folder and any sub folders. The problem is that the metadata, such as the created and modified date, seemed to be stripped out. This is a problem because when I try to list the items inside of the zip, only the files are shown but not directories.

```
import zipfile
import os


with zipfile.ZipFile("testing.zip", 'a') as zip_file:
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("test_dir"):
    for local_file in files:
        zip_file.write(os.path.join(root, local_file))


print("Created Zip with Python")
with zipfile.ZipFile('testing.zip') as zip_file:
    list = zip_file.infolist()
    for item in list:
        print(item.filename)

print("Zip created with 7Zip")
with zipfile.ZipFile('test_dir.zip') as zip_file:
    list = zip_file.infolist()
    for item in list:
        print(item.filename)
```

I first zip up the directory. Then I print out the files in the resultant zip. I then print out the files from another zip that I generated with a third party program. Here is the output from the program

```
Created Zip with Python
test_dir/A Test Doc.txt

Zip created with 7Zip
test_dir/
test_dir/A Test Doc.txt
```

The third party program prints out the directory, the python generated zip does not. Is there some way to keep the metadata when zipping up a directory? This is under Python 2.7.6 on Windows.

Comment: No, those are two completely different problems.

Comment: Is it something with my code or with how python handles Zips?